# Set Style for user control

Tags: wpf, user-controls, styles, resourcedictionary, dynamicresource

I am trying to set a style for my user control. The UserControl is in a project "Controls" and the theme is in a project "MainProject"

```
<UserControl x:Class="Controls.OutputPanel"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        x:Name="OutputControl"> 
   <!-- Style="{DynamicResource UserControlStyle}"> - I cant set the style here because the Resource Dictionary hasn't been defined yet -->

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/MainProject;component/Themes/MyTheme.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <!-- Now that the Resource Dictionary has been defined I need to set the style -->      

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBox x:Name="textbox" 
                   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                   Text="{Binding ElementName=OutputControl, Path=TextProperty}"
                   IsReadOnly="True"
                   Style="{DynamicResource OutputTextBoxStyle}"/>

    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Comment: In my experience the best thing to do is to load in your resource dictionary in the app resources. This makes it available at the start of the application.

Comment: the project is a UserControlLibrary so there is no App.xaml file to do this in

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That should be working fine as far as I can see. Do you get any special warnings or errors or do some parts from the Style not get applied?

To set the Style after `Resources` has been set, you can use the following syntax

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MainProject;component/Themes/MyTheme.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.Style>
    <DynamicResource ResourceKey="UserControlStyle"/>
</UserControl.Style>
```

If you're still having problems after this you can compare it to my sample app which I uploaded here: http://www.mediafire.com/?q1v98huubzw02zb

Comment: Thanks Very much, Had a look at your example and got it working :)

Answer (score 1):

You could make new resource dictionary, define your style there and than add it in app resources.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:UC="clr-namespace:UserControls;assembly=UserControls">
   <Grid>
      <UC:myUserControl/>
   </Grid>
</Window>


<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:UC="clr-namespace:UserControls;assembly=UserControls">

    <Style TargetType="UC:myUserControl">
       ...
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And